# Intrigued by (->) as instances of monad and functor

Tags: haskell

I am quite intrigued by `(->)` when I looked up in information about `(->)` in ghci. It says,

```
data (->) a b -- Defined in `GHC.Prim`
```

So far so good, but then it gets very interesting when it says -

```
instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in `GHC.Base`
instance Functor ((->) r) -- Defined in `GHC.Base`
```

What does this implicate? Why does GHC define it as an instance of a Monad, and Functor for `(->)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can be a bit confusing at first, but one important concept to remember is that `(->)` is not a monad or functor, but `(->) r` is.  `Monad` and `Functor` types all have the kind `* -> *`, so they only expect one type parameter.

What this means is that `fmap` for `(->) r` looks like

```
fmap g func = \x -> g (func x)
```

Which is also known as

```
fmap g func = g . func
```

which is just normal function composition!  When you `fmap g` over `func`, you change the *output type* by applying `g` to it.  In this case, if `func` has the type `a -> b`, `g` must have a type like `b -> c`.

The `Monad` instance is bit more interesting.  It lets you use the result of a function application "before" that application has occurred.  What helped me understand was seeing an example like

```
f :: Double -> (Double,Double)
f = do
    x1 <- (2*)
    x2 <- (2+)
    return (x1, x2)

> f 1.0
(2.0, 3.0)
```

What this does is apply the implicit argument to `f` to each of the functions on the right hand side of the binds.  So if you pass in `1.0` to `f`, it will bind the value `2 * 1.0` to `x1` and binds `2 + 1.0` to `x2`, then returns `(x1, x2)`.  It really makes it easy to apply a single argument to many subexpressions.  This function is equivalent to

```
f' x = (2 * x, 2 + x)
```

Why is this useful?  One common use is the `Reader` monad, which is simply a newtype wrapper around `(->) r`.  The `Reader` monad makes it easy to apply a static global config across your application.  You could write code like

```
myApp :: Reader Config ()
myApp = do
    config <- ask
    -- Use config here
    return ()
```

And then you run your application with `runReader myApp initialConfig`.  You can easily write actions in the `Reader Config` monad, compose them, chain them together, and all of them have access to the global, readonly config.  In addition, there's a companion `ReaderT` monad transformer which allows you to build it into your transformer stack, letting you have very complex applications that have easy access to static configuration.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. The part - "It lets you use the result of a function application "before" that application has occurred." - is most enlightening.

Comment: `f :: Double -> Double`should be `f :: Double -> (Double, Double)`

Comment: @TheInternet Thanks for fixing that, I started the function one way and ended it another, and forgot to go back to fix it.

Comment: @YogeshSajanikar Glad I could help =)  Like I said, that's what made it really click for me.  To be honest, it's something I don't get to use very often, but when I see a very complex function where a single argument is applied to many subexpressions I'll refactor to use do notation.  Occasionally it can really clean up your code and make it more readable, provided the reader understands what the `(->) a` monad does!

Comment: One place I use this is defining "predicate combinators" like `(<||>) = liftM2 (||)`. Now you can build combined predicates easily `isAlpha <||> isLetter <||> (== 'c') :: Char -> Bool` is a pretty silly example. To me, `satisfy $ isAlpha <||> isLetter <||> (== 'c')` looks nicer than `satisfy $ \c -> isAlpha c || isLetter c || c == 'c'`.

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be a bit less confusing if Haskell had just always allowed type operator sections:

```
data a->b

instance Monad (r -> )
```

looks much more natural.

For short explanation: I find it quite helpful to consider the special case `Monad (Bool -> )`, which is basically a two-element container type. It has the two elements

```
\case
  False -> elem1
  True -> elem2
```

So you can think about the functor instance much the same as for lists: map over "all contained elements".

The applicative and monad instances are a bit different, it might help to make the "container transformation" explicit:

```
data Pair a = Pair a a

instance Functor Pair where
  fmap f (Pair a b) = Pair (f a) (f b)

instance Monad Pair where
  return a = Pair a a
  join (Pair (Pair a _) (Pair _ b))
      = Pair       a            b
```

Comment: The `Applicative`/`Monad` instances make sense in the vein of constant containers and zipping. Considered as a container, `(r ->)` has constant size and thus enforces that the `Monad` and `Applicative` instances reflect that.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The example over Bool is really helpful.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Consider `pure`/`return` on `[]` as canonically defined—it produces a singleton list. It's not possible to have a "singleton" `(Bool ->)` container, though, so that intuition will throw you. Most "container" types behave that way, but something like an [infinite stream](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streams-3.1.1/docs/Data-Stream-Infinite.html) doesn't—it always has to have infinitely many elements so `pure`/`return` just makes them all the same value. The intuition you get about `Applicative`/`Monad` there is exactly the same as what we see with `(r ->)`.

Comment: The whole thing is called a "representable functor". Whenever a functor `f` is isomorphic to some function from some source data (i.e. `exists r . forall a . f a ~ r -> a`) we call it representable, likely will think of it as being "fixed size" (the size is determined by that chosen `r`), and will have `Applicative`/`Monad` instances much like `(r ->)` would.

Comment: As usual, Edward Kmett has the Haskell library to look into: [reprsentable-functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/representable-functors-3.2.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Representable.html). Direct from the Haddocks, "Representable endofunctors over the category of Haskell types are isomorphic to the reader monad and so inherit a very large number of properties for free." Ignore the "endo" and "category" bits and you've got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can check yourself, for example at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html

Copied from there:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)

instance Monad ((->) r) where
    return = const
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

Comment: How does this explain it?

Comment: @TheInternet Sorry, I actually misread the question. "Where" instead of "Why". But doesn't the code speak for itself? :)