# Is eta reduction possible?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

Is it possible to apply eta reduction in below case?

```
let normalise = filter (\x -> Data.Char.isLetter x || Data.Char.isSpace x )
```

I was expecting something like this to be possible:

```
let normalise = filter (Data.Char.isLetter || Data.Char.isSpace)
```

...but it is not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work, because `(||)` works on `Bool` values, and `Data.Char.isLetter` and `Data.Char.isSpace` are of type `Char -> Bool`.

[pl](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree#Tool_support) gives you:

```
$ pl "f x = a x || b x"
f = liftM2 (||) a b
```

Explanation: `liftM2` lifts `(||)` to the `(->) r` monad, so it's new type is `(r -> Bool) -> (r -> Bool) -> (r -> Bool)`.

So in your case we'll get:

```
import Control.Monad
let normalise = filter (liftM2 (||) Data.Char.isLetter Data.Char.isSpace)
```

Comment: A nice addition to this ([stolen from @JAbrahamson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026021/intrigued-by-as-instances-of-monad-and-functor/21026411#comment31608950_21026411)) is to define `(<||>) = liftM2 (||)`, then you can use it as `filter (isLetter <||> isSpace)`, and even continue to combine these like `filter (isLetter <||> isSpace <||> (== '1'))`.  I find this style to be particularly easy to use and attractive.

Answer (score 7):

```
import Control.Applicative
let normalise = filter ((||) <$> Data.Char.isLetter <*> Data.Char.isSpace)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution worth looking at involves arrows!

```
import Control.Arrow

normalize = filter $ uncurry (||) . (isLetter &&& isSpace)
```

`&&&` takes two functions (really arrows) and zips together their results into one tuple. We then just uncurry `||` so it's time becomes `(Bool, Bool) -> Bool` and we're all done!

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of the `Any` monoid and the monoid instance for functions returning monoid values:

```
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Char

let normalise = filter (getAny . ((Any . isLetter) `mappend` (Any . isSpace)))
```